# how to get price for outbound call in twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

so I am trying to get price for each call as one of my task requirements. I know that when call is completed there should be its price, but in case of outbound call I receive call status callback and at that moment there is parent call price but not a child call price. I have configured status callback url in twilio directly.

So what I was trying to do with inbound is to get call sid from status response body -> do client.calls(callId).fetch(); for parent call and client.calls.list({ parentCallSid: callId }) for child call -> receive prices in those calls and calculate 1 price for whole call.

In case of outbound call I receive child and parent call in completed statuses, but child call is missing price. Also important thing to mention, I was answering a call, it last some time and then I finished it. I am not considering timeout for unknown period of time as a solution (I was able to fetch price in a minute, but I don't know when it was generated). How do you handle this issue in your projects? Should I do 2-3 times per day requests to twilio to retrieve prices for all calls in that period of time? Or maybe there is some sort of callback or webhook?

Comment: Can you format this code in a way that it actually looks like code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [StatusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#statuscallback-request-parameters) webhook to collect the call's duration and length of recording. Use the duration and length of the recording to determine the cost of the call.

When Twilio sends parameters to your application in an asynchronous request to the StatusCallback URL, they include the same parameters passed in a synchronous TwiML request.

The status callback request also passes these additional parameters:

> CallDuration: The duration in seconds of the just-completed call.
>
> RecordingDuration: The duration of the recorded audio (in seconds).

Next, use the [Twilio Voice Pricing REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/pricing?code-sample=code-get-voice-prices-for-number-by-origination-number&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x) to determine the pricing in place for your account:

```
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var number = NumberResource.Fetch(
    originationNumber: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15108675310"),
    pathDestinationNumber: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661")
);

Console.WriteLine(number.OutboundCallPrices);
```

The response from the above:

```
{
  "country": "United States",
  "destination_number": "+15017122661",
  "inbound_call_price": {
    "base_price": null,
    "current_price": null,
    "number_type": null
  },
  "iso_country": "US",
  "origination_number": "+15108675310",
  "outbound_call_prices": [
    {
      "base_price": "0.013",
      "current_price": "0.013",
      "origination_prefixes": [
        "ALL"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "price_unit": "USD",
  "url": "https://pricing.twilio.com/v2/Voice/Numbers/+18001234567"
}
```

Current base price should be what you also find on your invoices from Twilio.

To be clear, there will be some rounding but and good luck getting this to exactly match what [Twilio will charge you](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179868-How-much-will-my-application-cost-per-minute-) (don't forget there are several legs to a call). If you are doing this to bill your customers this should allow you to create the billing business rules.