Twilio API : how to get all the costs linked to a Call SID?
I created several phone numbers on Twilio.
I use different Twilio APIs with these phone numbers (STT (Speech To Text) Gather, TTS, etc...).
When a call is done to one of these Twilio phone numbers, the call is identified by Twilio with a 'Call SID', and then costs are generated namely by the STT and TTS, and also by the "inbound minutes" and "outbound minutes".
I would like to know how to get the total costs linked to a call (that is to say to a Call SID).
How to get this total cost ? (with python, PHP or whatever code)
Here is my code but does't seem to include all costs (namely not the TTS and SST costs):
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
call = client.calls(call_sid).fetch()
print(f"Price: {call.price} {call.price_unit}")

Thanks !

Can you provide an MRE for your question so we know some effort was put forth?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76869370/how-to-get-price-for-outbound-call-in-twilio

What does you call retun as-is? Did you go over the APl docs cIoseIy?
